# ApplicationException throws unhandled exception in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

This comes from a book but won't debug with correct message in my Visual Studio 2010, it just gives me Unhandled exception at `throw new ApplicationException("Smth. bad happened", e);`
Is there an error in the book or is it my VS2010 exception settings maybe? The console output is supposed to show that given the file does not exist the inner and outer trace will be printed along with File Not Found. Does it have to do with Just-in-time debugging?
Current Output:Unhandled Exception.........................................................
Desired output:http://www.introprogramming.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/clip_image008.png

```
  class program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            string fileName = "WrongFileName.txt";
            ReadFile(fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Smth. bad happened", e);
        }
    }
    static void ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName);
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to understand the difference between code that fails to **compile** and code that fails when it **runs**.  It compiles, it is not supposed to run.

Comment: I used the wrong terms- it does not compile properly with the correct console output. So if you can help me get the proper output Unhandled Exception: Exception1: Msg1 ---> Exception2: Msg2 instead of exception only I would be grateful.

Comment: My code fails to output a message- it is clear that there is an unhandled exception for educative purposes. My goal is not to compile, but to display the inner stack trace as shown in the book.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wrap an exception in your own and have it bubble up, you should remove the inner `try`, since every *try* needs a matching `catch`.  Since you're wrapping an exception of your own with the original exception, it doesn't serve any purpose if you are immediately catching it.

```
try
{
    string fileName = "WrongFileName.txt";
    ReadFile(fileName);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("Smth. bad happened", e);
}
```

EDIT:

This is expected behavior.  You're explicitly throwing an exception, and no one is handling it.  The book is likely trying to make the point that you can wrap exceptions to provide additional information, while still preserving the original exception.  Check to ensure that the file you're trying to open is in the right place.

As an additional note, you should really wrap the file stream in a `using` block to ensure that the underlying handles/resources are closed.

```
static void ReadFile(string fileName)
{
    using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will edit my post, that wasn't the problem, thanks for pointing out my bad copying, now it is edited.

Comment: The output is supposed to show that given the file does not exist the inner and outer trace will be printed along with File Not Found. Sorry but your answer does not help me. Please review my question as i have added some info to it: the output is supposed to show that given the file does not exist the inner and outer trace will be printed along with File Not Found.

Comment: Running this code does indeed print both the outer and the inner exceptions in the console output window, and throws a `FileNotFoundException`.  Try running the application without the debugger attached if you're not seeing it printed.  @PetarDrianov

Comment: That was my question and the answer is no. It does not print without the debugger( just running the exe file). So is you marked me down please undo that. Here is my desired output:http://www.introprogramming.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/clip_image008.png/

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you the file "WrongFileName.txt" is in your project's Bin/Debug folder (you include the file in the project and set it's build action to Content and Copy always, if you want it not to throw the exception.

I presume that the book was trying to show, that when the file name is correct, the program will go through normally, but otherwise will cause error.

The `catch` block gets run because the file doesn't exist in this case and therefore the action inside is executed. This concrete action is to throw the exception again but with more helpful information. You can also see, that this new exception's constructor accepts the original exception as the second parameter, which means it will be included in this exception's `InnerException` property.

Comment: Sorry, but you di not understand what the book is trying to show. The output is supposed to show that given the file does not exist the inner and outer trace will be printed along with File Not Found.

Comment: This is exactly what is happening really :-) . If you see the exception that is thrown, it contains all this information, but the program crashes, because there is nothing to catch it. In case you want to safely output the results, you would have to enclose the whole Main method's body in a new try-catch block and in the catch section output the exceptions traces to Console

Comment: I did not suceed to enclose the main method in a try catch block and I do not think that this is what you are suppose to do, if the innerException parameter is not a null reference, the current exception is raised in a catch block that handles the inner exception. If you can show me how to do it i will be gratefull, here is the link for the output:http://www.introprogramming.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/clip_image008.png

Comment: What do you exactly need? The inner and outer traces ARE shown on the image you sent so I can't understand this :-) .

Comment: This is what I am NOT getting.

Comment: Aah, I thought this was your screenshot ;-) . The main reason for this is that Visual Studio's debugger is intercepting the running program and in case of exception it redirect you in the debugging interface inside the IDE. If you want to get the output in the sample, click DEBUG -> Start without debugging in Visual Studio. This will run the program normally without the debugger attached and you will see your output there ;-) .

Comment: I am not getting anything printed after Ctrl+F5 and the debugger starts. Nothing is printed to the console.

Comment: I'm trying this and it works. Try my test project here - http://blog.mzikmund.com/wp-content/TestSO.rar

Comment: Your project is .NET 4.5 and I need 4.0 for VS 2010, i can not start your application- the code is the same. If you can resend it to me with .NET 4.0